# How to remove spaces from the end of text in an element. (XSL)

Tags: xslt

Does anyone know what XSL code would remove the trailing whitespace after the last word in an element?

```
<p>This is my paragraph.  </p>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: @joe, normalize-space() removes all starting whitespace and all trailing whitespace. It also replaces every group of internal whitespace with a single space. You don't have starting whitespace and all internal whitespace is just one space. With another input there could be more (unexpected) changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the [`normalize-space()` XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-normalize-space) function.

```
<xsl:template match="p">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" /></p>
</xsl:template>
```

Be careful, there is a catch (which might or might not be relevant to you):

> The [...] function returns the
>   argument string with whitespace
>   normalized by stripping leading and
>   trailing whitespace **and replacing
>   sequences of whitespace characters by
>   a single space**.

This means it also removes all line breaks and tabs and other whitespace and turns them into a single space.

Comment: This solution isn't correct because besides removing the trailing whitespace, it removes other spaces, too.

Comment: That's true. I guess this is better: http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200212/post10190.html

Comment: I emphasized the delicate bit in my answer. If it doesn't bother the OP, I guess normalize-space() is good enough.

Comment: it is not removing the spaces within the paragraph for me.

Comment: @joe, normalize-space() removes all starting whitespace and all trailing whitespace. It also replaces every group of internal whitespace with a single space. You don't have starting whitespace and all internal whitespace is just one space. With another input there could be more (unexpected) changes.

Comment: Unfortunately, the cited solution was one of my initial unsuccessful attempts at trim(). It doesn't work if the last non-space char is also present at other positions of the text. Also, trim() cannot be performed using a RegEx alone... :(

Comment: Can it not? "^\s+|\s+$" should do the job.

Comment: Is this use of "|" standard RegEx syntax?

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: Yes, it is. The pipe symbol defines an alternative - it is basically an "OR". The regex breaks down to plain English as "all white space at the start of the string OR all white space at the end of the string"

Comment: Then this is not at all what is needed, This matches the whitespace, but we need to skip this, not to match this.

Comment: Wee just need to replace all matches with the empty string. :-)

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: Significant simplification of the code, thanks to a hint from Tomalak.

**Here is an XPath 2.0 / XSLT 2.0 solution**, which removes only the trailing spaces:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 >
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    "<xsl:sequence select="replace(., '\s+$', '', 'm')"/>"
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<someText>   This is    some text       </someText>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
"   This is    some text"
```

You can see the XSLT 1.0 solution (implementing almost the same idea), which uses [**FXSL 1.x**](http://fxsl.sf.net), [**here**](http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200112/msg01067.html):

http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200112/msg01067.html

Comment: @Tomalak Probably yes, but I need to look in the reference books. When I was answering I had just some free seconds, so this reflects my rather superficial RegEx knowledge.

Comment: @Tomalak You are right. This trims a string:  replace(., '^\s+|\s+$', '', 'm') . The problem I know can't be achieved with RegEx is to say if a string contains balanced brackets.