# JAXB unmarshalling not tolerating whitespace around token enumerations

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, jaxb2

[JAXB 2](https://jaxb.java.net/) (Oracle / Metro version 2.2.7 and I suspect others as well) doesn't seem to tolerate whitespace around values in enumeration elements.

Minimal example follows. Both [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) and [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/) validate the instance against the schema. The puzzling think is that JAXB validation **doesn't complain** but returns **null** when trying to access the value. How can I configure it to return the value properly?

**update:** I 've tried associating an `XmlAdapter` to trim the strings, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419951/how-to-configure-jaxb-so-it-trims-whitespaces-by-default), but the result is the same.

**update II:** And here's [the ticket at Metro JAXB Jira](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-964).

### A.xsd

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="foo://a" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns="foo://a">

   <xs:element name="type" type="Type"/>

   <xs:simpleType name="Type">
     <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
         <xs:enumeration value="Archive"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="Organisation"/>
       </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

### a.xml

```
<a:type xmlns:a="foo://a" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="foo://a A.xsd"
>Organisation </a:type>
```

(notice the whitespace after 'Organisation')

### unmarshalling code

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    JAXBContext payloadContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("a");
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = payloadContext.createUnmarshaller();
    unmarshaller.setSchema(schemaFactory.newSchema(new Source[]{new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(new File("A.xsd")))}));
    JAXBElement<?> oUnmarshalled = (JAXBElement<?>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("a.xml"));
    Object o = oUnmarshalled.getValue(); // returns NULL
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When I run the following code using the JAXB implementation in JDK 1.7.0_21-b12 for the Mac with the documents from your question I get the enum value as output.

```
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        StreamSource xsd = new StreamSource("src/forum17114304/A.xsd");
        StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("src/forum17114304/a.xml");

        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
                .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(xsd);
        schema.newValidator().validate(xml);

        JAXBContext payloadContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("a");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = payloadContext.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
        JAXBElement<?> oUnmarshalled = (JAXBElement<?>) unmarshaller
                .unmarshal(xml);
        Object o = oUnmarshalled.getValue(); // returns ORGANISATION
        System.out.println(o);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
ORGANISATION
```

---

**UPDATE**

There appears to be a bug in [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) for this use case:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/410853

This bug has been fixed in the EclipseLink 2.5.1 and 2.6.0 streams.  A nightly download can be obtained from the following link starting June 15, 2013:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

Comment: I confirmed that I get the same null with either: (a) the latest JAXB RI 2.2.7 from the Maven Repo, (b) the same from jaxb.java.net, or (c) the JDK 1.7.0_21-b11 on Ubuntu 12.04. I 'm gonna open a ticket on Metro's JAXB JIRA.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus - A bug also existed in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) for this use case.  I have fixed it in the EclipseLink 2.5.1 and 2.6.0 streams.  The fix should be available in the nightly downloads starting tomorrow.  If you are interested in trying out MOXy the following link will help you get started:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Answer (score 2):

Since (for the time being) I want to stick to JAXB RI (being drawn to the "RI" part alone), in the end I used the `replace(., '^\s+|\s+$', '', 'm')` in an XSLT 2.0 transformation as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753086/how-to-remove-spaces-from-the-end-of-text-in-an-element-xsl).

Relevant code section is:

```
    Source input = new StreamSource(new File("a.xml"));
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer wsTrimmer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File("transform-trim-all.xslt")));

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    wsTrimmer.transform(input, new StreamResult(bos));

    JAXBElement<?> oUnmarshalled = (JAXBElement<?>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()));
```

The code requires Saxon HE on the runtime path as the XSLT used is , I've used the following **ivy** dependency:

```
<dependency org="net.sf.saxon" name="Saxon-HE" rev="9.4"/>
```

**XSLT** is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
       <xsl:sequence select="replace(., '^\s+|\s+$', '', 'm')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```