# MOXy unmarshalling not tolerating whitespace before dateTime

Tags: java, eclipselink, moxy, jaxb2

This relates to the problem discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114304/jaxb-unmarshalling-not-tolerating-whitespace-around-token-enumerations).

I am having a similar problem with dateTime elements that contain whitespace in front of the dateTime value. I get a ConversionException with an "Incorrect date-time format ..." message.  If I remove all of the whitespace from in front of the value it works.  The other strange thing is that I have a custom adapter and it isn't called.

I am using MOXy 2.5, however, I only see the problem on the WebLogic 12c server, so I suspect that the 2.3.2 version that comes with WebLogic is actually being used when my application is deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue in EclipseLink 2.3.2 that is included with WebLogic 12.1.1.  This issue has since been fixed.  Here is a link to an article I wrote that demonstrates how to point to a newer version of EclipseLink using a shared library in WebLogic:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/10/updating-eclipselink-in-weblogic.html

---

> The other strange thing is that I have a custom adapter and it isn't
>   called.

Can you provide more details about your adapter?

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I will upgrade the eclipselink version used by WebLogic.  Regarding the adapter, the whitespace issue is the real problem.  XML parsing is failing due to the whitespace issue before the adapter is called.